# Fixing type errors when accessing object value dynamically i.e. myObject[`VALUE_${variable}`]

Tags: typescript

I've got following object

```
const CHARACTER_ITEMS = {
  ITEM_ARMS_LIGHT: "",
  ITEM_LEGS_LIGHT: "",
  ITEM_ARMS_HEAVY: "",
  ITEM_LEGS_HEAVY: ""
}
```

I then want to access some values of this object in a dynamic way i.e

```
const variant = 'HEAVY'; // This is dynamic, based on server response
const arms = CHARACTER_ITEMS[`ITEM_LEGS_${variant}`]
```

Unfortunately this throws an error

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on
>   type '{ ITEM_ARMS_LIGHT: any; ...

I tried typing my `variant` like this

```
const variant: 'HEAVY' | 'LIGHT' = 'HEAVY';
```

but had no luck, same error comes up. Is there any way to fix this without using a disable comment and preserving type safety? i.e. `variant` will always have correct value that resolves to entry in `CHARACTER_ITEMS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus far cleanest way I found is to create a helper function like this

```
export function getDynamicAsset<T>(resource: T, path: string) {
  const typedPath = path as keyof typeof resource;

  return resource[typedPath];
}
```

And use it this way

```
getDynamicAsset(CHARACTER_ITEMS, `ITEM_LEGS_${variant}`)
```

Comment: Is that giving you type safety? You can pass anything into the `path` parameter, and you're then using an unsafe cast, so it isn't quite type-safe as far as I can see?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use string concatenation/interpolation if you're doing this. There's a similar example explained [here](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#constants) where it says:

> ...make sure to use simple string literal assignment with const. This limitation is coming from the type-system, because all the dynamic string operations (e.g. string concatenation, template strings and also object used as a map) will widen the literal type to its super-type, `string`

So I think your best bet might be to have a function which converts your variant to the specific string literals which represent properties of `CHARACTER_ITEMS`.  Here's one possible solution:

```
const convert = (member: "ARMS" | "LEGS", weight: "LIGHT" | "HEAVY") : keyof typeof CHARACTER_ITEMS => {
    if (member === "ARMS")
        return weight === "LIGHT" ? "ITEM_ARMS_LIGHT" : "ITEM_ARMS_HEAVY"
    else
        return weight === "LIGHT" ? "ITEM_LEGS_LIGHT" : "ITEM_LEGS_HEAVY"
}

const variant = 'HEAVY'; // This is dynamic, based on server response
//const arms = CHARACTER_ITEMS[`ITEM_LEGS_${variant}`]
const arms = CHARACTER_ITEMS[convert("ARMS", variant)]
```